# NullPointerException again

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

Logs:

```
12-25 03:26:16.003: E/AndroidRuntime(3623): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-25 03:26:16.003: E/AndroidRuntime(3623): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dd.gfit/com.dd.gfit.DaysActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-25 03:26:16.003: E/AndroidRuntime(3623):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
12-25 03:26:16.003: E/AndroidRuntime(3623):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
12-25 03:26:16.003: E/AndroidRuntime(3623):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
12-25 03:26:16.003: E/AndroidRuntime(3623):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
12-25 03:26:16.003: E/AndroidRuntime(3623):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-25 03:26:16.003: E/AndroidRuntime(3623):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-25 03:26:16.003: E/AndroidRuntime(3623):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
12-25 03:26:16.003: E/AndroidRuntime(3623):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-25 03:26:16.003: E/AndroidRuntime(3623):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-25 03:26:16.003: E/AndroidRuntime(3623):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-25 03:26:16.003: E/AndroidRuntime(3623):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-25 03:26:16.003: E/AndroidRuntime(3623):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-25 03:26:16.003: E/AndroidRuntime(3623): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-25 03:26:16.003: E/AndroidRuntime(3623):     at com.dd.gfit.DaysActivity.onCreate(DaysActivity.java:22)
12-25 03:26:16.003: E/AndroidRuntime(3623):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
12-25 03:26:16.003: E/AndroidRuntime(3623):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
12-25 03:26:16.003: E/AndroidRuntime(3623):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
12-25 03:26:16.003: E/AndroidRuntime(3623):     ... 11 more
```

Below I've added the relevant code.

MySQLiteHelper.java:

```
package com.dd.gfit;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class MySQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

  public static final String TABLE_DAYS = "days";

  public static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
  public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";
  public static final String COLUMN_ID_ROUTINE = "id_routine";
  public static final String COLUMN_DAY = "day";


  private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "gfit.db";
  private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

  public MySQLiteHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        // create days table
        database.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_DAYS + "(" 
                + COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement," 
                + COLUMN_ID_ROUTINE + " integer not null," 
                + COLUMN_NAME + " varchar not null," 
                + COLUMN_DAY + " varchar not null"
                + ")");
        database.execSQL("insert into " + TABLE_DAYS + "("+ COLUMN_ID +", "+ COLUMN_ID_ROUTINE +", "+ COLUMN_NAME +", "+ COLUMN_DAY +") VALUES (12, 23, 'Day 1', 'Monday')");
        database.execSQL("insert into " + TABLE_DAYS + "("+ COLUMN_ID +", "+ COLUMN_ID_ROUTINE +", "+ COLUMN_NAME +", "+ COLUMN_DAY +") VALUES (21, 23, 'Day 2', 'Tuesday')");
        database.execSQL("insert into " + TABLE_DAYS + "("+ COLUMN_ID +", "+ COLUMN_ID_ROUTINE +", "+ COLUMN_NAME +", "+ COLUMN_DAY +") VALUES (33, 23, 'Day 3', 'No Specific Day')");
  }

  @Override
  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_DAYS);
    onCreate(db);
  }

}
```

DaysActivity.java:

```
package com.dd.gfit;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

public class DaysActivity extends ListActivity {
  private DaysDataSource datasource;
  private long routineDataID;
  private SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_days);

    routineDataID = getIntent().getLongExtra("routineDataID", 1);

      Cursor cursor = datasource.fetchAllDays(routineDataID);

      // The desired columns to be bound
      String[] columns = new String[] { MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_NAME, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_DAY };

      // the XML defined views which the data will be bound to
      int[] to = new int[] { R.id.listitem_day_name, R.id.listitem_day_day };

      // create the adapter using the cursor pointing to the desired data 
      dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.listitem_day, cursor, columns, to, 0);

      // Assign adapter to ListView
      setListAdapter(dataAdapter);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
      inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_days, menu);
      return true;
  }

}
```

DaysDataSource.java:

```
package com.dd.gfit;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

public class DaysDataSource {

  // Database fields
  private SQLiteDatabase database;
  private MySQLiteHelper dbHelper;
  private String[] allColumns = { MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID_ROUTINE, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_NAME, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_DAY };

  public DaysDataSource(Context context) {
    dbHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(context);
  }

  public void open() throws SQLException {
    database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
  }

  public void close() {
    dbHelper.close();
  }

  public Cursor fetchAllDays(long id) {   
      Cursor mCursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_DAYS, allColumns, null, null, null, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID_ROUTINE + " = " + id, null);

      if (mCursor != null) {
          mCursor.moveToFirst();
      }

      return mCursor;
  }
}
```

listitem_day.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listitem_day_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Day Name" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listitem_day_day"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:text="Monday"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</LinearLayout>
```

How the intent for DaysActivity is called:

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(id), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toast.show(); 

Intent startDaysActivity = new Intent(this, DaysActivity.class);
startDaysActivity.putExtra("routineDataID", id);
this.startActivity(startDaysActivity);
```

I know that `routineDataID` is being passed successfully because the `Toast` is displaying the `id` properly.

Why am I getting a NullPointerException?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change you code as:

```
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_days);

    routineDataID = getIntent().getLongExtra("routineDataID", 1);

    datasource=new DaysDataSource(DaysActivity.this); //<<missing this line

    datasource.open() ;  //<<< Open db here       

    Cursor cursor = datasource.fetchAllDays(routineDataID);
     // your code here...
```

you are not initializing datasource by passing Context of Activity

Answer (score 0):

```
   Cursor cursor = datasource.fetchAllDays(routineDataID);
```

datasource is null

Comment: This answer would be improved by giving some suggestions on how to avoid the problem.  It might be that the constructor needs to be beefed up, or there is some sequencing problem with function calls, or insufficient checking in the identified line.  Your diagnosis, as far as it goes, is correct; it just isn't all that helpful. (The answer got flagged as a 'Low Quality Post' — and the edit I applied was trivia that you should have spotted yourself).

Comment: My answer clearly for the asked question, question was **Why** I've answer **Because** I did not write this code, and there are a few ways how to make datasource not null,  I think all is simply :) **Merry Christmas !!!**